# PDF file not showing or downloading in nginx server

Tags: nginx

I've been searching this all day, not founding a solution. Here's the problem:
My VM is running ubuntu with nginx server for my php apps. My application works fine except I cant see or download PDF files in the browser.

I'll try to describe most of my configuration for you to help me solve this problem:

nginx 1.6.2
php 5.5.26

my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  sendfile    on;
  server_tokens on;
  types_hash_max_size 1024;
  types_hash_bucket_size 512;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_max_size 512;

  keepalive_timeout  65;
  tcp_nodelay        on;

  gzip         on;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

my /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.conf:

```
server {
    listen    80;
    server_name   app.dev;
    client_max_body_size 1m;
    root /_dev/www/app.com.br/public_html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset   UTF-8;

    access_log    /etc/nginx/www.access.log;
    error_log     /etc/nginx/www.error.log;

    location / {

      root  /_dev/www/app.com.br/public_html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
      index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

      root  /_dev/www/app.com.br/public_html;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php$is_args$args;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
   }

    location ~* (.*\.pdf) {
        types { application/octet-stream .pdf; }
        default_type application/octet-stream;
    }

    sendfile off;
  }
```

when i click the button that triggers the script to get the pdf file the response headers are:

```
Cache-Control:private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=1
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="romaneio.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 18 Jun 2015 21:59:18 GMT
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 18 Jun 2015 21:59:18 GMT
Pragma:public
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

BUT THE BROWSER DOESN'T OPEN IT OR DOWNLOAD IT. WHAT CAN IT BE ? THANK YOU ALL !

**Edit:** The console log that I took from the ajax response shows a bunch of stuff, seems like a PDF file code, why the reason the browser doesn't open or download then ?

**Edit 2:** Well, after a thorough research I found tcpdf doesn't work well with ajax calls, any idea on a good pdf library that allows ajax calls ?

Comment: Any reason there is no `content-length`?  And is gzip in the mix... 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: How can I see the version of gzip ? about content-length I dont have a clue :(

Comment: It does not looks like your nginx's headers. Are you sure the request goes to your server?

Comment: The `transfer-encoding` is `chunked`, it doesn't need a `content-length`.

Comment: Show `curl -v http://app.dev/file.pdf` result

Comment: not found, but what about the headers ?